# How to use ActivexObject in Java for opening Outlook Application?

Tags: java, outlook

How to use ActivexObject in Java for opening Outlook Application

1. My aim is to open an outlook new mail in which to, cc, Subject and Body should be predefined which is ready to send.
2. So thought to use ActivexObject, but no clue on how to use it in Java.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Jacob. There are quite a few posts that dela wit husing Jacob to access the Outlook Object Model, such as [JAVA JACOB Outlook get all contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939967/java-jacob-outlook-get-all-contacts)